# Parse node in google feed file with php?

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I have a google feed file like below.

```html
<item>
<g:id><![CDATA[147]]></g:id>
<g:title><![CDATA[ Kemerli Pantolon Dar Kesim 300-07 Pembe]]></g:title>
<g:description><![CDATA[ Kemerli Pantolon Dar Kesim 300-07 Pembe Özellikleri: RENK : Pembe KUMAŞ : g Cotton, 0 Viscose , %3 Lycra PANTOLON BOY : 92 cm MANKENİN ÜSTÜNDEKİ ÜRÜNÜN BEDENİ : 38 MEVSİM : Dört Mevsim AKSESUAR : Aksesuarlar ürüne dahil değildir. MANKENİN ÖLÇÜLERİ : Basen : 90 cm Bel : 60 cm Göğüs : 88 cm Boy : 168 cm Kilo : 50 kg ]]></g:description>
<g:link><![CDATA[https://www.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe]]></g:link>
<g:image_link><![CDATA[https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-1134-14-B.jpg]]></g:image_link>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
<g:identifier_exists>yes</g:identifier_exists>
<g:price><![CDATA[29.91 TRY]]></g:price>
<g:brand><![CDATA[Dar Kesim Pantolon]]></g:brand>
<g:google_product_category><![CDATA[Kıyafet ve Aksesuarlar > Giyim Eşyaları > Pantolonlar]]></g:google_product_category>
<g:product_type><![CDATA[Giyim > Pantolon > Dar Kesim Pantolon]]></g:product_type>
<g:custom_label_0>Degil</g:custom_label_0>
<g:sale_price><![CDATA[]]></g:sale_price>
<g:sale_price_effective_date><![CDATA[]]></g:sale_price_effective_date>
<g:gtin><![CDATA[300-07]]></g:gtin>
<g:gender>kadın</g:gender>
<g:age_group>adult</g:age_group>
<g:additional_image_link>https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-1134-14-B.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
<g:additional_image_link>https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-1135-14-B.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
<g:additional_image_link>https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-1136-14-B.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
</item>
```

I'm trying to parse this file with the XMLReader class and save it to the database. I parsed all the noteType as below.

```html
    $xmlReader = new XMLReader();
        $xmlReader->open('http://.........');
        while ($xmlReader->read()) {

            if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->localname == "item") {
                $xmlReader->read();
                $item = array();

            }
            
            if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->prefix == "g") {

                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'id') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:id'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'title') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:title'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'description') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:description'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'link') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:link'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'image_link') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:image_link'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'condition') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:condition'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'availability') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:availability'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'identifier_exists') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:identifier_exists'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'price') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:price'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'brand') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:brand'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'google_product_category') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:google_product_category'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'product_type') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:product_type'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'custom_label_0') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:custom_label_0'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'sale_price') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:sale_price'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }
                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'sale_price_effective_date') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:sale_price_effective_date'] = $xmlReader->value;
                }


                if ($xmlReader->localName == 'gtin') {
                    $xmlReader->read();
                    $item['g:gtin'] = $xmlReader->value;
                    $items[] = $item;
                }


            }

        }
        $date = new DateTime('NOW');
        $kayit_tarih = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $kontrol_tarih = $date->format('Y-m-d');
       
        foreach ($items as $value) {
            $id = $value['g:id'];
            $description = $value['g:description'];
            $title = $value['g:title'];
            $link = $value['g:link'];
            $image_link = $value['g:image_link'];
            $condition = $value['g:condition'];
            $availability = $value['g:availability'];
            $identifier_exists = $value['g:identifier_exists'];
            $price = $value['g:price'];
            $brand = $value['g:brand'];
            $google_product_category = $value['g:google_product_category'];
            $product_type = $value['g:product_type'];
            $sale_price = $value['g:sale_price'];
            $sale_price_effective_date = $value['g:sale_price_effective_date'];
            $gtin = $value['g:gtin'];
            $in_up_Data = $this->model("readerModel")->xmlInsert($id, $title, $description, $condition, $link, $image_link, $image_link, $image_link, $availability, $identifier_exists, $price, $brand, $google_product_category, $product_type, $sale_price, $sale_price_effective_date, $gtin, "Boyutlandırılmadı", $kayit_tarih, $kontrol_tarih);
            

        }
```

But

```html
<g:additional_image_link>https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-1134-14-B.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
<g:additional_image_link>https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-1135-14-B.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
<g:additional_image_link>https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-1136-14-B.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
```

I could not parse.
How can I parse the knot here and transfer it to the loop. I tried a lot of things. But I have to use XML Reader Class reasonably. After parsing, I register it in the database. There is no problem in saving it in the database.  The problem is I can't parse image paths with the same tag as I mentioned above.

How can I do it ? Can you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify a lot of the boilerplate code from XMLReader by importing each `<item>` node into a SimpleXMLElement.  This makes it easier to process each full element in one go.

In this code, each `<item>` uses a `foreach()` loop to extract all child elements into a separate array (the `$item` array). If this item has already been encountered, then the item is converted into an array of items and each subsequent one added to the list...

```
$xmlReader = new XMLReader();
$xmlReader->open('http://.........');
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
while ($xmlReader->read()) {
    
    if ($xmlReader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlReader->localName == "item") {
        // Load the XML under the <item> tag into SimpleXML
        $data = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($xmlReader->expand(), true));
        $item = [];
        // Loop over the child elements from the 'g' namespace
        foreach  ($data->children("g", true) as $tag => $value )    {
            $tag = "g:".$tag;
            // If an item with that tag name already exists, convert it to an array of items
            if ( isset($item[$tag]) )   {
                if ( !is_array($item[$tag]))    {
                    $item[$tag] = [$item[$tag]];
                }
                $item[$tag][] = (string)$value;
            }
            else    {
                // For normal items, add in the value (as a string) to the array
                $item[$tag] = (string) $value;
            }
        }
        // Store new item
        $items[] = $item;
    }
}
```

So your array will contain something like...

```
Array
(
    [g:id] => 147
    [g:title] =>  Kemerli Pantolon Dar Kesim 300-07 Pembe
    [g:description] =>  Kemerli Pantolon Dar Kesim 300-07 Pembe Özellikleri: RENK : Pembe KUMAŞ : g Cotton, 0 Viscose , %3 Lycra PANTOLON BOY : 92 cm MANKENİN ÜSTÜNDEKİ ÜRÜNÜN BEDENİ : 38 MEVSİM : Dört Mevsim AKSESUAR : Aksesuarlar ürüne dahil değildir. MANKENİN ÖLÇÜLERİ : Basen : 90 cm Bel : 60 cm Göğüs : 88 cm Boy : 168 cm Kilo : 50 kg 
    [g:link] => https://www.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe
    [g:image_link] => https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-1134-14-B.jpg
    [g:condition] => new
    [g:availability] => in stock
    [g:identifier_exists] => yes
    [g:price] => 29.91 TRY
    [g:brand] => Dar Kesim Pantolon
    [g:google_product_category] => Kıyafet ve Aksesuarlar > Giyim Eşyaları > Pantolonlar
    [g:product_type] => Giyim > Pantolon > Dar Kesim Pantolon
    [g:custom_label_0] => Degil
    [g:sale_price] =>       
    [g:sale_price_effective_date] =>        
    [g:gtin] => 300-07
    [g:gender] => kadın
    [g:age_group] => adult
    [g:additional_image_link] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-1134-14-B.jpg     
            [1] => https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-1135-14-B.jpg     
            [2] => https://cdn.tesetturpazari.com/kemerli-pantolon-dar-kesim-300-07-pembe-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-pantolon-dar-kesim-1136-14-B.jpg     
        )
)
```

You will have to decide how you are going to process these items, but this will extract the data for you.